# QtCreator does not recognize cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, qt-creator, linux-mint

Even though I have set the cmake executable path (/usr/local/bin/cmake) via (Tools > Options > Build & Run > CMake), when I try to open a cmake project (or create a new one), I encounter the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the (Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits > Manual > Desktop), the `Compiler` was not set. I set it to "GCC (X86 64bit in /usr/bin)" and the issue was fixed.